# loading html files with jQuery load() not working when delivered with flask

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I've seen similar threads on StackOverflow but it doesn't seem to work. I'm building a simple webapp where the user uploads a docx file and a python script does some processing and returns mp3 files for the user to download.

My script also generates a bunch of HTML files (contents of the doc) that I want to display on my webpage, eg loading text1.html into index.html. But I'm running into two problems:

1. the text (text1.html) only appears when I open the page (index.html) HTML file directly and doesn't show when I load the web app with flask
2. text1.html only appears when it is in static/templates folder.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
          integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("text1.html");
    });
    </script>
</head>



<body>
<h3>Heading</h3>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data id="form1">
  <input type=file name=uploadfield1>
<!--  <input id="ub" name=uploadbutton1 type=submit value=Upload >-->
  <button type="submit" name="uploadbutton1" value=Upload>Upload </button>
  <button type="button" name="removebutton" value="Remove">Remove </button>

</form>

<form method ="post" enctype=multipart/form-data >
  <button type="submit" name="tag1"  value="tag2">Process</button>

</form>


<p>
  text selected:
</p>

<div id="includedContent"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

and text1.html

```
<p> sample text from text1.html that is in projectfolder/templates folder </p>
```

I tried changing `$("#includedContent").load("text1.html");` to `$("#includedContent").load("/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/static/text1.html");` but that didn't work as well..

so what is the correct way of loading in external HTML files? Furthermore, since the files I'll be loading will be generated after `index.html` is loaded in, is there a better way to load these files? As I'm assuming things inside the static folder should be, well, static.

Comment: Check this and check your link, is your path correct to text1.html? https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score -1):

You can use ajax for it, it will not reload the page and can get the response.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",// method
url: `${window.location.pathname}`, // route
data: {
  "key":"value" // json format in key value pair
},
contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
success: function (res) {
  console.log(res); // contents of text1.html
   }
});
```

You can use `request.form.get("key") # key for the value` and then return the text1.html

```
return render_template("text1.html")
```

Comment: .load is a ajax call by it self, you dont need this. https://api.jquery.com/load/